# How to await fs.readFile?

Tags: node.js

I'm having problems with awaiting `fs.readFile()`
I have a file where I want to iterate over each line, and save non-duplicated inside of an array `domains`.

However, when I call my function with `fs.readFile` and after it I call `console.log(domains)` domains is empty.

Code

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var re = /@(.*?):/;
let domains = [];

const parseProviders = () => {
    fs.readFile("file.txt", (error, data) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    data
      .toString()
      .split("\n")
      .forEach((line, index, arr) => {
        try {
          line = line.match(re)[1];
          if(!domains.includes(line)) {
            domains.push(line);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          throw err;  
        }
      });
      console.log(domains); // this would work and print an array with non-duplicate items
  });
}

(() => {
  parseProviders();
  console.log(domains); // prints an empty array []
})();
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promise_example (and fwiw, your code is missing the actual call to `fs.readFile`)

Comment: I'm not sure why that didn't copy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of different things you could do here. (note that in the below code samples I've deliberately simplified things to make them easier to read) You could

**1. Amend your function to take a callback that gets executed by the readfile callback**

```
const parseProviders = (callback) => {
    fs.readFile("file.txt", (error, data) => {
      data
        .toString()
        .split('\n')
        .forEach(line => domains.push(line))
    });
  });
}

(() => {
  parseProviders(() => {
    console.log(domains);
  });
})();
```

**2. Make use of the `fs/promises` module as suggested by @robertklep in the comments. If you do this you should turn it into an async function**

```
const  { readFile } = require("fs/promises")

const parseProviders = async (callback) => {
    const data = await readFile("file.txt")
    data
      .toString()
      .split('\n')
      .forEach(line => domains.push(line))
  });
}

(async () => {
  await parseProviders()
  console.log(domains);
})();
```

**3. Manually promisify the readFile function.**

```
const parseProviders = () => {
    return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
      fs.readFile("file.txt", (error, data) => {
      data
        .toString()
        .split('\n')
        .forEach(line => domains.push(line))
        accept();
      });
  });
}

(async () => {
  await parseProviders()
  console.log(domains);
})();
```

- Note - you don't need to do this, but its worth knowing *how* to do it for when you are dealing with other callback style APIs.

Answer (score 1):

you could use callback

```
var fs = require("fs");
var re = /@(.*?):/;
let domains = [];

const parseProviders = (callback) => {
    fs.readFile("file.txt", (error, data) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    data
      .toString()
      .split("\n")
      .forEach((line, index, arr) => {
        try {
          line = line.match(re)[1];
          if(!domains.includes(line)) {
            domains.push(line);
          }
        } catch (err) {
          throw err;  
        }
      });
      console.log(domains); // this would work and print an array with non-duplicate items
      callback(domains)
  });
}

(() => {
  parseProviders((res)=>{
  console.log(res); // prints an empty array []

});
})();
```