# Node.JS Page only loads about 50% of the time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function called parsedata in my node.js file which is called when a user logs in. After parsedata() is called, the server switches to a new screen. However, this only works every other time. I put an asynchronous wait in between, which made it work about 90% of the time but I am just wondering why it is doing this. I believe it has something to do with all of the helper functions which are being used but I am not completely sure. Any info or help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
app.post("/login.html", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  await parseData();
  //await sleep(750);
  res.redirect(__dirname + "/homescreen.html");
});

async function parseData() {
  let dates = await findCommon();
  let maxStreak = await getMaxStreak(dates);
}

async function findCommon() {
  var dates = new Set();
  var data = await fs.readFile(__dirname + "/mem.txt", "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    return data;
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] === "*" && i + mostRecentName.length < data.length) {
      if (data.slice(i + 1, i + mostRecentName.length + 1) == mostRecentName) {
        while (data[i] != "\n") {
          i++;
        }
        if (i < data.length - 1) {
          i++;
        }
        while (data[i] != "*" && i < data.length) {
          let curr = "";
          let count = 10;
          while (count > 0) {
            count--;
            curr += data[i];
            i++;
          }
          while (data[i] != "\n") {
            i += 1;
          }
          if (i < data.length - 1) {
            i++;
          }
          dates.add(curr);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  dates = Array.from(dates);
  dates = await bubbleSort(dates);
  return dates;
}

async function getMaxStreak(dates) {
  let today = new Date();
  let year = today.getFullYear().toString();
  let month = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  let day = today.getDate().toString();

  if (month.length == 1) {
    month = "0" + month;
  }
  if (day.length == 1) {
    day = "0" + day;
  }

  let testDate = year + "-" + month + "-"+ day;

  if (!(testDate in dates)) {
    dates.push(testDate);
  }
  let streak = 1;
  for (let i = dates.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let options;
    if (i == dates.length - 1) {
        options = await convert(testDate);
    } else {
        options = await convert(dates[i]);
    }
    if (dates[i - 1] == options[0] || dates[i - 1] == options[1] || dates[i - 1] == options[2]) {
      streak++;
    } else {
      return streak;
    }
  }
  return streak;
}

async function convert(date) {
  let option1Day = (parseInt(date.slice(8, 10)) - 1).toString();
  if (option1Day.length == 1) {
    option1Day = "0" + option1Day;
  }
  let option2Month = (parseInt(date.slice(5, 7)) - 1).toString();
  if (option2Month.length == 1) {
    option2Month = "0" + option2Month;
  }
  let option2Day = "30";
  let option3Day = "31";
  let option1 = date.slice(0, 8) + option1Day;
  let option2 = date.slice(0, 5) + option2Month + "-" + option2Day;
  let option3 = date.slice(0, 5) + option2Month + "-" + option3Day;
  return [option1, option2, option3];
}
```

Comment: change `fs.readFile` in `fs.readFileSync`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Nick. However, now it does not seem to load at all. Should I be using an await before the fs.read or not?

Comment: fs.readFileSync doesn't return a promise, is, as the name says, a syncronous op. It doesn't expect a callback and by default it returns a buffer, check that [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options)

Comment: Using `await` with `fs.readFile` will only work if you import it using `fs/promises` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150882/how-to-await-fs-readfile

Comment: @Nick thank you for the clarification. It still works about half the time. It is very strange because it is following a strict pattern of working and then not working (to better explain if it is the nth time I run it and n is odd then it works, otherwise it does not). Any idea as to why this may happen?

Comment: I can't help more than that since i don't have enough information, anyway, convert shouldn't be async

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It has something with the macro and micro tasks.Your code has the same result with the following codes:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  findCommon().then(dates => {
    getMaxStreak(dates).then(maxStreak => {})
  })
     
  resolve()
})
.then(() => { 
  res.redirect(__dirname + "/homescreen.html")
})
```

`res.redirect` will be added into the micro task queue;
then, `getMaxStreak` will be added into the micro task queue too.
finally, we will take out the first task of the micro task queue to execute, yes, it's `res.redirect`, not `getMaxStreak`.

Comment: How does this solve the issue?

Comment: What you say is true, but on a practical level this code produces the same error because it  synchronously calls `resolve` in the new Promise executor without waiting for the `findCommon` promise chain to complete.

Comment: sorry, my thought is wrong, it has nothing to do with macro and micro task queue.And there  are some errors when you run your code? You might replace `res.redirect` with `console.log` to take a look, make sure if console.log run every time.